Выполнение конструкции if со второго цикла
у меня есть задача, в которой используется конструкция if
и я хочу сделать так, чтобы эта конструкция начала проверятся только со второго цикла.
n = 0
for i in range (...):
    n += 1
    if n != 1 and ...
    elif n != 1 and ...

мне приходится в каждом условии проверять, что этот цикл идет уже не первый раз, чтобы он начал выполнятся. Можете подсказать какие то более простые способы проверки этого условия, чтобы это было короче.

Чем различаются ваши иф и елиф? Если на первом обороте цикла ничего не делается, то просто начните range не с нуля, а с единицы

вместо троеточий может быть любой текст, это не важно в моем вопросе

for i in range (1, stopvalue):
   ...


Если у тебя уже
for i in range(...):

то проверка делается через
if i:

Если там не range, то можно использовать
for i,x in enumerate(...)

